# Camel Netty4 TCP Connection issue on openshift

Tags: java, apache-camel, openshift

I have used below path in camel configuration on local machine :
from("netty4:tcp://0.0.0.0:10001?sync=true") -- It is working fine on local machine
cmd-> netstat -ano | findstr 10001
TCP    0.0.0.0:10001          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       19596
Also able to send messages on this above TCP connection

But while deploying on openshift with same camel configuration TCP connection get started and able to Listen on port 10001 as shown below
tcp        0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/java
tcp        0      0 :::10001                :::*                    LISTEN      1/java

but not able to send any message on 10001 port it is showing error as :

1. connection timeout from outside pods
2. open connection on same pod but not able to send message (trying with command - nc localhost 10001)

Answer (score 0):

I think this have nothing to do camel netty. When deploy in openshift, you need to define the service and expose the port so that it can accessible from outside of the pod.

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/architecture/core_concepts/pods_and_services.html